# How to use Ruby Vector class in IRB

Tags: ruby, vector

I tried [Ruby cross_product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-cross_product) in IRB. but it gives an error.

```
irb(main):055:0> Vector[1, 0, 0].cross_product Vector[0, 1, 0]
NameError: uninitialized constant Vector
```

How can I test Vector class in IRB?

Comment: ruby-doc.org tip: require any file listed in the "In Files" section on the top left of the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to require 'matrix' library, just

```
require 'matrix'
```

in irb session.